# Get service in appends attribute

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Model that looks something like this:

**Rewards Earned Model:**

```
class RewardsEarnedModel extends BaseModel{

    protected $appends = ['readable_date'];

    public function getReadableDateAttribute(){
        // How do I access the User Service?
        return $this->userService->dateTime($this->attributes['created_at'])->readableDate;
    }

    public function scopeSums($query, User $user, $offset = 0, $limit = 50){
        return $query-> /* add items here (snipped) */;
    }

}
```

I then run the model like this from my controller:

**Rewards Controller:**

```
public function getRewards(Request $request, User $user, $date = null){
    $rewards = new RewardsEarnedModel;
    $rewards = $rewards->Sums($user);

    $sums = $rewards->get()->toArray();
}
```

My `User` service class has a `Time` trait attached to it. In that trait there is the function `dateTime`, and I would like to access it from my `getReadableDateAttribute` method, but I can not seem to do so. What can I do to access it from my `User` service?

**User Service:**

```
namespace App\Services;
class User {
    use Time;
}
```

**Time trait:**

```
namespace App\Traits;
trait Time{
    public function dateTime($datetime = null){
        /* Snipped code */
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `$user->readable_date` working?

Comment: `$user->readable_date` isn't an option.

Comment: What I am trying to do is format the value from the database in the users saved timezone

Comment: Just put the trait in your User model to use it from that model.

Comment: Then you can use it using `$this->dateTime` without any problem.

Comment: User is a service not a model

Comment: Well, you can use `app(RewardsEarnedModel::class)->dateTime`.

Comment: I updated `getReadableDateAttribute` and added to the question.

Comment: can I do something like `app()['services']['user']->dateTime()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able access the User service by doing `app()->User` here is the final result:

```
public function getReadableDateAttribute(){
    return app()->User->dateTime($this->attributes['created_at'])->readableDate;
}
```